# Calculating Time Difference between 2 Dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am calculating the time difference between 2 dates in ticket system.  In the main table I have RowID, TicketID, TicketCategory, CreatedMoment.  When the ticket is resolved it will show on another table in column Statuschange and the common field in both tables is the RowID.  Example table below:

Table 1

```
RowID    TicketID    TicketCategory    Createdmoment      Status
1234     11223344    PC Installation   12 Nov 2014 0800    1
1235     11223355    Server Config     12 Nov 2014 0930    1
```

Table 2

```
TicketRowID    Statuschange      OldStatus   NewStatus
1234           13 Nov 2014 1300    1           2
1235           13 Nov 2014 1100    1           2
```

In the above example the tickets are resolved at 11am and 1pm the next day,  in the report I am making I am counting the number of tickets resolved before 12pm the next day so in the above example report will show I have closed 1 ticket and 1 is pending.  I have to run the query for last month's data to show in daily format.  Need help with the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope the following code snippet will help:

```
declare @tab table (RowID int, TicketID varchar(100), TicketCategory varchar(100)
, Createdmoment datetime, [Status] int)

insert into @tab
select 1234,'11223344','PC Installation','12 Nov 2014 08:00',1
union
select 1235,'11223355','Server Config','12 Nov 2014 09:30',1


declare @tab2 table (TicketRowID int, Statuschange datetime, OldStatus int, NewStatus int)
insert into @tab2
select 1234, '13 Nov 2014 13:00',1, 2
union
select 1235, '13 Nov 2014 11:00', 1, 2

select *, dateadd(HH, 12, convert(datetime, cast(dateadd(day,1,t1.Createdmoment) as date))) NextDay12PM from @tab t1
select * from @tab2 t2

select t1.RowID, t1.TicketID, t1.TicketCategory, t1.Createdmoment, t2.Statuschange as 'Closedmoment', NewStatus
, case when t2.Statuschange <  dateadd(HH, 12, convert(datetime, cast(dateadd(day,1,t1.Createdmoment) as date))) then sum(1) else sum(0) end as 'Resolved'
, case when t2.Statuschange >  dateadd(HH, 12, convert(datetime, cast(dateadd(day,1,t1.Createdmoment) as date))) then sum(1) else sum(0) end as 'Pending'
from @tab t1
left join @tab2 t2 on t2.TicketRowID = t1.RowID
group by t1.RowID, t1.TicketID, t1.TicketCategory, t1.Createdmoment, NewStatus, t2.Statuschange
```

Thanks.